# add new columns to and existing csv file in python. The new columns is a time series data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, append

I have excel file with 10 columns and 10 rows, I need to append a .txt file to each of rows (like to add a new column to whole data). The .txt file is time series data. How can I do it?
I dont know which approach I should use.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data = pd.read_csv('file.txt', header=None)
df = pd.read_excel('/content/Cartel1.xlsx')
df['Date'] = (data.values)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Template Txt file:

2019-03-01

2019-03-02

2019-03-03